# [UIImage imageWithRenderingMode:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance

Tags: ios, objective-c

I am trying to display original tab bar images. The following code works fine in iOS7, but gives above crash for ios 6.0. Following is the code in `AppDelegates` `didFinishLaunchingWithOptions`

```
UITabBar *tb = tabBarControllerProperty.tabBar;
        NSArray *itemsObject = tb.items;
        for(UITabBarItem *tabItem in itemsObject)
        {
            UIImage *imaged = tabItem.image;
            tabItem.selectedImage = imaged;
            tabItem.image = [imaged imageWithRenderingMode:UIImageRenderingModeAlwaysOriginal];// crash for ios6, not in ios 7
        }
```

Comment: Hey John Doe,  Not sure if this helps, but I had the same problem, using imageWithRenderingMode in iOS 7 to work around the broken tintForSelectedImage.  Turns out that tintForSelectedImage works find in 6, so use [[UIImage class] instancesRepondToSelector to check if the method is available, and use the old white + alpha image with tintForSelected.. in iOS 7.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

From the documentation:

`-[UIImage imageWithRenderingMode:]`

> Availability: available in iOS 7.0 and later.

You have to check if the method is available during runtime:

```
if ([imaged respondsToSelector:@selector(imageWithRenderingMode:)]) {
    tabItem.image = [imaged imageWithRenderingMode:UIImageRenderingModeAlwaysOriginal];// crash for ios6, not in ios 7
} else {
    // iOS 6 fallback: insert code to convert imaged if needed
    tabItem.image = imaged;
}
```

Comment: then how to make it compatible with ios 6? Need to show original tab bar icons in ios 6 as well

Answer (score 1):

Your app is crashing because `-imageWithRenderingMode:` is added in iOS 7 and can only be used in iOS 7 and above

https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UIImage_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UIImage/imageWithRenderingMode:

Answer (score 1):

The crash is occurring because that function is only available, per the docs, starting with iOS 7:

imageWithRenderingMode:
Creates and returns a new image object with the specified rendering mode.

> Availability Available in iOS 7.0 and later.

You will have to test if it is available on the UIImage object and then take an alternative approach if it is not:

```
  if (imaged respondsToSelector:@selector(imageWithRenderingMode:)])
   {
         tabItem.image = [imaged imageWithRenderingMode:UIImageRenderingModeAlwaysOriginal];// crash for ios6, not in ios 7
   }
   else
   {
      // alternatives...maybe nothing to do here...?
      tabItem.image = imaged;
   }
```

Answer (score 0):

From `apple's docs`

imageWithRenderingMode:
Creates and returns a new image object with the specified rendering mode.

```
- (UIImage *)imageWithRenderingMode:(UIImageRenderingMode)renderingMode
```

Return Value
A new image object with the specified rendering mode.

Availability
**Available in iOS 7.0 and later.**